# any improvement in following linqtosql query where i shouldn't need select if possible

Tags: linq-to-sql

following is my query

```
 return await (from ofr in _context.table1
                          join aca in _context.table2
                          on new { a = ofr.f1, b = ofr.f2}
                         equals new { a = (int?)aca.f1, b = aca.f2}
                          where lstStatusesTocheck.Contains(ofr.status)
                          select new { ofr.id }
                          ).CountAsync();
```

can i avoid select new { ofr.id } and directly get the count somehow

Comment: Yes, if you use method instead of query syntax. You can get rid of the JOIN too if you use LINQ-to-SQL (or rather EF Core) properly, as an ORM instead of embedded SQL. It's the ORM's job to generate the JOIN clauses from the navigation properties between entities. You can write eg `await _context.Orders.Where(order=>lstStatusesTocheck(order.Product.Status)).CountAsync()`.

Comment: Why do you think `new { ofr.id }` is necessary? If you just use `select ofr` you have the method syntax equivalent.